# Neon Pothos slowly rotting

Tags: plant-health, indoors, leaves, watering, roots

So I’ve got this neon Pothos around five weeks ago and since then the leaves are slowly turning yellow and rotting at the bottom. [image: here are some I removed today] 
[image: also today] and I really don’t know what to do bc I read that it can be under watering or overwatering. I touched the soil and it’s moist  one inch down and I watered three days ago.

Have you guys ever experienced that with neon Pothos? I have green and marble Pothos at my room too and they seem fine.

Comment: Assuming the pot has drainage holes, do you empty out the tray at the bottom 30 minutes after you water so its not left sitting in water?

Comment: Idk if it was precisely after 30 minutes, but I did empty any remaining water on the tray